# Using a named query in a hbm with import class

Tags: nhibernate, class, import, named-query, hbmxml

In my MSSQL server I have a SQL view called AllFavourite. In order to load the data into my DTO class I have the following in my hbm.xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
       namespace="Domain.Model.Entities" assembly="Domain.Model">
  <import class="AllFavourite"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In my code I have the following.

```
public IList<AllFavourite> GetFavourites(int userId)
{
    var query = Session
        .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM AllFavourite where UserId=:UserId")
        .SetInt32("UserId", userId)
        .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(AllFavourite)));
    return query.List<AllFavourite>();
}
```

This works great and produces the results that I am after, however I would like to move the SQL from code into a named query into the hbm.xml file. So my hbm.xml file now looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
namespace="Domain.Model.Entities" assembly="Domain.Model">
  <import class="AllFavourite"/>
  <query name="GetAllFavouriteByUserId">
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT * FROM AllFavourite WHERE UserId=:UserId
    ]]>
  </query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my code now looks like this

```
public IList<AllFavourite> GetFavourites(int userId)
{
    var query = Session
        .GetNamedQuery("GetAllFavouriteByUserId")
        .SetInt32("UserId", userId)
        .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(AllFavourite)));
    return query.List<AllFavourite>();
}
```

However when I run this I get an error:-

> Parameter UserId does not exist as a
>   named parameter in [SELECT * FROM
>   AllFavourite WHERE UserId=:UserId]

So my question is it possible to use a named query in this manner?

Comment: Seems correct to me... try using a different named parameter than :UserId (e.g. :uid) and check for weird unicode charachters ;)

Comment: @Ehrann - I have just tried that but it does not work. I can't work this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query` tag expects a HQL query:

```
<query name="GetAllFavouriteByUserId">
    <![CDATA[
    from AllFavourite where UserId = :UserId
    ]]>
</query>
```

If you want to write a native sql query you should use the `sql-query` tag:

```
<sql-query name="GetAllFavouriteByUserId">
    <return alias="foo" class="Foo"/>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT {foo.ID} as {foo.ID}, 
           {foo}.NAME AS {foo.Name} 
    FROM sometable 
    WHERE {foo}.ID = :UserId
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```

Comment: aha, just saw your edit. I see now that there is a difference between <query> and <sql-query>  Many thanks.

Comment: and everyone

I'm trying with your example of `<sql-query...` but it's not working.
I'm getting this error:

**Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "return".**

Although I've declared a type attribute for the return tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need this?

```
<query-param name='UserId' type='Integer'/>
```

Comment: My code works without it using Darin's answer. However will also try your answer with <query ...> and get back to later.